# How to get the integral of a monthly distribution function?

Tags: python

I want to get the integral of a monthly distribution function, for a list of start dates and end dates.
The monthly arrival frequency is as below.

| Month | Arrival Frequency (%) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.2 |
| 6 | 3.6 |
| 7 | 12.5 |
| 8 | 28.7 |
| 9 | 34.6 |
| 10 | 18.3 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 12 | 0.1 |

And I want to get the integral, for example, the period is from 9/1/2019 to 7/13/2020.

Comment: So you want to sum the values in a column? What are you having trouble with? You didn't post a [mre] so we don't know how this table is being stored in your code, nor do we know how you're filtering by date range. If you have zero code in your question then there can't really be any answers that will necessarily specifically help you in your situation.

Comment: Sorry about that, had no idea about this community rule. I am also new to Python. I think this task is far beyond my current level of knowledge and abilities to start from scratch. Definitely I can do more research and try on my own..